# How to rotate without deforming

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm very new to blender so I decided to follow some tutorials and at a certain part a guy rotates a plank fine but when I do it the plank deforms, the shear tool and transform tool does the same, I've lost my entire day to this plank

tutorial I was using: https://youtu.be/zH_eZDWCnMg?t=630

[image: pain]

[image: pain2]

Comment: hello, it's hard to guess what's happening, maybe link the tutorial you're talking about, show some screenshots, etc

Comment: By deform, do you mean it has got thicker and has not rotated around the middle?  It is unclear to me still what the issue is but you may want to check your origin is in the correct place.  Perhaps you could provide the blend file as there ae a lot of modifiers there that may be the problem.